# cakephp 3 application transfer to webhoster

Tags: database, cakephp, web-hosting

I'm trying to transfer a cakephp3 application from my local linux server to a online webhoster.

I managed to migrate the database and put it online. The only way to connect to the internet for me is through a proxy right now. However this proxy blocks the website, so I'm using a webproxy (proxfree.net and hide.me) to access the website.

Whenever I try to login I get a 'invalid username or password'.
When I try to create a new user, it saves a record, but with an empty field for the pseudonym (username).

I wrote a test for the database connection

```
$db = ConnectionManager::get('default');
echo "To database ".($db->isConnected()?"connected":"disconnected")."\n";
```

It says it's connected to the database. I'm also able to print the usernames on the login-site, so the database-connection works definitely.

Login: [marcusmoenius.bplaced.net/app/users/login](http://marcusmoenius.bplaced.net/app/users/login)

Add user: [marcusmoenius.bplaced.net/app/users/add](http://marcusmoenius.bplaced.net/app/users/add)

Does anyone know, why I can't login? Is anyone else able to login? It worked on my local machine

example username and password:

username: Stella

password: Superman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was no problem with the webspace, but with my understanding of the cakephp-functionality.

Apperantly the passwords-hashes don't match on the webhoster. So I needed to add new users with new-hashed passwords.
  But the registration of new users didn't work, because I marked the pseudonym-field as not _accessible in the users-table. So when I invoked the patchEntity-method in the controller, it didn't apply the pseudonym-field and hence didn't put a valid record in the database.